# Calculate CRC32 checksum with Objective-C

Tags: java, objective-c

I am trying to convert my Java code in Objective-C.

Java code:

```
pDataResult = "105501005523069400E4100300000000000000000000000000000000"

checksum.update(pDataResult, 0, 12);
long checksumValue = checksum.getValue();
```

In Objective-C:

```
#include <zlib.h>;

NSString *testString = @"105501005523069400E4100300000000000000000000000000000000";
NSData *testData = [testString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
Byte *testByte = (Byte *)[testData bytes];

uLong crc2 = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
long long result2 = crc32(crc2, &testByte, 12);

NSLog(@"file crc32 checksum %llu", result2)
```

In Java the checksumValue is equal to 4253726258 but in Objective-C it is 752296094.

UPDATE

I have tried with this version

```
    Byte * j=Byte * j= {0x10, 0x55, 0x01 ,0x00, 0x55 ,0x23, 0x06, 0x94,0x00 ,0xe4, 0x10, 0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,‌​0x00};
    NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&j length:sizeof(j)] ;

    uLong crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
    long long result = crc32(crc, &j, 12);
    NSLog(@"file crc32 checksum %llu", result);
```

I have got that now

**429518402**

Comment: Where is the `crc32` function from in the Objective-C code? Why do you call it twice?

Comment: from the zlib I have followed this tuto http://scalebean.blogspot.com/2015/02/crc32-calculation-on-java-and-objective.html

Comment: In the Java code you are doing the checksum on a string. In the Objective-C you are doing the checksum on the data for the UTF-8 representation of the string.

Comment: I have try with that   
   Byte * j= {0x10, 0x55, 0x01 ,0x00, 0x55 ,0x23, 0x06, 0x94,0x00 ,0xe4, 0x10, 0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}; the value is  429518402

Comment: What are those bytes? Those bytes don't come anywhere near close to representing the string.

Comment: It looks like your Java code is passing a `String` to the method `update` which takes a `byte[]`. What is your actual Java code, or am I misreading it?

Answer (score 0):

I have spent all days with that. I have just use the CryptoSwift and the result was correct.